# In emacs with X, Edit->Copy is mapped to "<copy>" - what key is that on a Linux based PC?

Tags: emacs, ubuntu, x11, keymapping

In my Linux setup, Emacs has the Edit->Copy menu item mapped to  -- what key is that?  And where does it get that keyname definition from?  Is that internal to emacs? Or does it get that further upstream?

Specifically, I am running Gnome under Ubuntu Lucid (10.04LTS) - but I believe this is a far more generic question.

Is it, perhaps, that it is mapped to non-existant keys on a standard keyboard? (I recall earlier Sun keyboards having such keys.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a standard X11 keysym for which there are no equivalents on a 105-key PC keyboard.  Sun and various other workstation keyboards had such keys, and you can find them on some multimedia PC keyboards.

Comment: How do I remap/bind Emacs' "<copy>" to some other shortcut, like `W-c` for example?

Comment: You could do it inside of Emacs by finding out the function it's running (in the Emacs I have in front of me, it's `ns-copy-including-secondary`) and binding that to a key, or you can bind the X11 `Copy` keysym to a physical key using `xmodmap`.  (Note that `xmodmap` cannot bind a keysym to a specific modifier+keysym sequence, though, with the exception of `Mode_switch` and `Shift` modifiers — with some caveats, in particular that the `Shift` modifier tends to mean "extend the selection" and few X11 programs are smart enough to figure out that you put `Copy` itself on a `Shift` modifier.)

Comment: I misunderstood. When I enter `M-x` `clipboard-yank` Emacs tells me I can just use `<paste>` and likewise when I enter `clipboard-kill-ring-save` it says I can just use `<copy>`. I can't remap those keys because I don't have those keys. I can remap the functions they run to other keys.

Comment: Ok, so you're looking for `xmodmap`.  But, as I said, you need physical keys to bind it to; keysyms map to physical keys, not to logical keys with modifiers.  So on a standard 105-key keyboard you would need to rebind keys like `Menu`, or on an exended keyboard you can use `xev` to find out the keycodes used by the added keys and then rebind those.